# how to get checkbox values in form in jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, dialog

I have a form in a jquery dialogue.  How do I get the values of the selected checkboxes once the form is submitted?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<form id="myform" action=""><input type="checkbox"   id="completeCheck" name="completeCheck" value="" />Complete check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="view" value="Car" /> View report <br /><input type="checkbox" name="consist" value="" />Consistency check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="other" value="" />Other checks<br /><input type="checkbox" name="keyCheck" value="" />Key check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="compareCheck" value="" />Compare check<br /></form>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Data check',
        buttons: {
          "Submit Form": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
          "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    });

$('#createNew').click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
    return false;
});

$('form#myform').submit(function(){

  $dialog.dialog('close');
});        


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/9mZAJ/2/ *or* http://jsfiddle.net/9mZAJ/1/

`$('#completeCheck').is(':checked')` will do the trick along with `.each` loop on checkbox rest see demo and below code.

This should help

Now to loop through all the check boxes you can do that in several ways using `.each` and with `is(":checked")` check. `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<form id="myform" action=""><input type="checkbox"   id="completeCheck" name="completeCheck" value="" />Complete check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="view" value="Car" /> View report <br /><input type="checkbox" name="consist" value="" />Consistency check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="other" value="" />Other checks<br /><input type="checkbox" name="keyCheck" value="" />Key check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="compareCheck" value="" />Compare check<br /></form>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Data check',
        buttons: {
          "Submit Form": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
          "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    });

$('#createNew').click(function() {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
    return false;
});

$('form#myform').submit(function(){
    alert('completeCheck checkobox is checked or not ==> ' + $('#completeCheck').is(':checked'));

  $dialog.dialog('close');
});        


});​
```

**loop like this**

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
})
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: @user840930 Glad I can help, cheerios! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the checked checkboxes with `$(this).find(":checked")` within your form submit-callback. You could then loop over them and get their values.

Here's an example of how you could store the names of the checked checkboxes and their values in an array for instance:

```
$('form#myform').submit(function(){
  // Store names of the checkboxes and their values in an array
  var values = []; 
  $(this).find(":checked").each(function () {
     values[$(this).prop("name")] = $(this).val();
  });
  $dialog.dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: @Tats_innit OP wants to "get the values of the selected checkboxes once the form is submitted?", not check if a certain checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

In your submit function:

```
$(this).find(':checkbox').each(function(){
    if(this.checked)
        alert(this.name + ' is checked');
    else
        alert(this.name + ' is not checked');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tricki/mwJqR/2/

Comment: You can use `this.checked` instead of `$(this).is(':checked')`, by the way. Saves unnecessary function calls.